# Is there a way to have Dropbox remember the last page I was on in a PDF file?

Tags: dropbox, pdf, online-storage

1. I like to store my PDF files in the Dropbox cloud.
2. I like to access these PDFs from my PCs, laptop and Android 'phone.
3. When I open a PDF it always starts on page 1 no matter what page I was on previously.

Is there a way to have Dropbox remember the page I was on?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, but you can use Foxit reader to open the document, create a bookmark of the page you last read and move the bookmark to the beggining of the bookmark list. So, next time you open the document, just click the bookmark entry you created before :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "mount" the dropbox file system so that bookmarks and such are handled exactly as for a local file by the pdf readers ?

Comment: Do you want to ask a new question? Because I'm a bit distracted by the question mark at the end of your sentence.

Comment: Not really, you can indeed mount dropbox in a file explorer app (did it on my tablet but forgot which one it is)